# The working copy “Pods” failed to commit files - Realm Errors

Tags: xcode, swift, github, cocoapods, realm

I am unable to commit my Xcode project changes to Github due to the following error. As you can see below, it's related to Realm. I updated the pods recently. Any advice on how to fix this.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: So it seems like you checkin your `Pods` directory in to git. Can you run `git status` in your project directory in Terminal.app and show the output here?

Comment: Based on your comment, I assume I am not supposed to commit the "Pods" folder to Github. This happened when I upgraded to the latest Xcode. Never had that option before. The output is too long. Going to edit my post with screen shots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want to commit your `Pods` directory to Git, which ensures that your projects can be always compiled when you checkout a certain revision without having to run `pod install` before, then you could reset what you have in your staging area in the `Pods`directory by running the following commands in your project directory:

```
git rm --cached -r Pods
git add -A Pods
```

(Disclaimer: You can lose data by running such commands. Please familiarize yourself with what they mean if necessary, so that you don't delete by accident what you want to commit.)

Alternatively, you can add the `Pods` directory to your `.gitignore` file. This will ensure that you can't commit the `Pods` directory in future, but it will be necessary that `pod install` is run after changes to the `Podfile.lock` when e.g. switching branches, collaborating and on CI.

You can achieve that by executing the following command on the shell in your project directory:

```
 echo "/Pods" >> .gitignore
```

After doing that, you need to commit the changes to your `.gitignore` to your repository. Furthermore I'd recommend to make a dedicated commit to your repository where you remove the files under the `Pods` directory. This will then affect only the repositories contents and not your local checkout.

---

The CocoaPods Guide "Using CocoaPods" has a chapter ["Should I check the Pods directory into source control?"](https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/using-cocoapods.html#should-i-check-the-pods-directory-into-source-control), which discusses in length the advantages and disadvantages of that:

> ### Should I check the Pods directory into source control?
>
> Whether or not you check in your `Pods` folder is up to you, as
>   workflows vary from project to project. We recommend that you keep the
>   Pods directory under source control, and don't add it to your
>   `.gitignore`. But ultimately this decision is up to you:
>
> #### Benefits of checking in the Pods directory
>
> - After cloning the repo, the project can immediately build and run, even without having CocoaPods installed on the machine. There is no
>     need to run `pod install`, and no Internet connection is necessary.
> - The Pod artifacts (code/libraries) are always available, even if the source of a Pod (e.g. GitHub) were to go down.
> - The Pod artifacts are guaranteed to be identical to those in the original installation after cloning the repo.
>
> #### Benefits of ignoring the Pods directory
>
> - The source control repo will be smaller and take up less space.
> - As long as the sources (e.g. GitHub) for all Pods are available, CocoaPods is generally able to recreate the same installation.
>     (Technically there is no guarantee that running `pod install` will
>     fetch and recreate identical artifacts when not using a commit SHA in
>     the Podfile. This is especially true when using zip files in the
>     Podfile.)
> - There won't be any conflicts to deal with when performing source control operations, such as merging branches with different Pod
>     versions.
>
> Whether or not you check in the `Pods` directory, the `Podfile` and
>   `Podfile.lock` should always be kept under version control.

---

In addition, you might want to check, whether your `.gitignore` can be improved. I can recognize from the screenshots for example that you have a `xcuserdata` directory in your Xcode project, which Git doesn't ignore. Those are user-specific configuration files and don't necessarily belong into a repository. If you collaborate with others, ignoring those reduces the size of the repo and the noise in pull requests and makes change sets easier to review. But as above it is ultimately up to you, whether you want to check them in or not. GitHub hosts a crowd-sourced repository with file templates for a wide variety of languages. [Their Objective-C file](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Objective-C.gitignore) might be good starting point for you.